# Backslash in interactive interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reading python tutorial from the official documentation and came across this --> "In the interactive interpreter, the output string is enclosed in quotes and special characters are escaped with backslashes." and gave it a try.

[image: Output in Interpreter:]

So, why did it print backslash in the second output while it didn't in first output?, Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the string is displayed in this way, if its contents use only one kind of quote, Python uses the other kind of quote to surround the whole string, to make the display less cluttered.  Your first example uses a single-quote (apostrophe) but no double quotes, so Python is able to display it using double-quotes and not have to escape anything.

You can see the opposite behavior if you create a string that contains double quotes but not single quotes:

```
>>> 'a "quote" here'
'a "quote" here'
```

Note that Python here uses single quotes around the whole string.

In your second example, your string contains both double and single quotes.  This means one or the other has to be escaped, so Python chooses (apparently arbitrarily) to use single quotes around the whole string, and escape single quotes that occur within it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.how do you know which quote will be escaped? :#

Comment: @PruthviRaj: It appears that if both quote types occur in a string, Python always escapes the single quotes.  I don't know if that's actually documented behavior, it's just what it looks to me like it's doing.  Is there a reason it matters?  This is only a display issue; it has no effect on what's actually in the string.

Comment: No there's no reason it matters. But I just wanted to have a clear understanding. Thank you very much! ;)

Answer (score 0):

String quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the string; for example, r"\"" is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; r"\" is not a valid string literal

check [this](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html) as it might help as well, more specifically head to 2.4.1